# XML validation in spark java

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark

We have got a 3GB XML which we have to validate and then flatten. We are expected to use Spark-Java to validate it and flattening as well. Flattened data will be ingested into Hive table.
Also, the validation should throw the bad record in XML (so that we can write the same back to Kafka topic to make source system aware of it). And bad record shouldn't get stored inside hive table.
Flattening based on com.databricks.spark.xml is not recommended by client.
Kindly help . If not code, algorithm would also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javax.xml.validation.Validator. This api will help you to validate XML.

Comment: I tried it doing it with the help of the Validator class. But still am unable to remove the record which is corrupt as per XSD.